# How to search for a file in a directory and read its names and print out largest numbered file using Ant?

Tags: ant, directory-listing, fileset, dirset

I need to develop an ANT script that reads a directory content. The files in this directory are numbered along with its name. I have to find the largest numbered file in this directory and return its name and the number.

For example:

```
>> ls
patch-aaa-050.jar
patch-aaa-051.jar
patch-aaa-052.jar
patch-aaa-053.jar
patch-aaa-054.jar
patch-aaa-055.jar
```

I need to echo out: `Latest patch is patch-aaa-055: Patched level: 55`

Although this is a very easy task in `Bash, PowerShell or Python`. I am a bit clueless in ANT. I have checked out `dirset` Type and `fileset` Type. These types are able to list the directories but parsing the file names are overwhelming for me. The design is to run only with ANT, so I am limited to use that tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [resource collection](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection) path combined with [basename](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html) and [script](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) task, f.e.:

```
<project>
 <path id="foo">
  <last>
    <sort>
      <fileset dir="C:/WKS/temp" includes="*.jar"/>
    </sort>
  </last>
 </path>

 <basename file="${toString:foo}" property="foobar"/>

 <script language="javascript">
   var a = project.getProperty('foobar').split('.')[0];
   var b = project.getProperty('foobar').split('-')[2].split('.')[0];
   print ('Latest patch is ' + a + ': Patched level: ' + b);
 </script>
</project>
```

There are also other possibilities for sort, see [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#sort)